# Custom Resolver Addon always has empty resolvedItems collection

Tags: sites-9.5, custom-resolver, add-on

When deploying any custom resolver Addon, the resolvedItems collection in the Resolve method is always empty (count = 0).

I suspect that the custom resolver is loaded BEFORE any of the OOTB resolvers (including standard and DXA resolvers), so there are no resolvedItems yet and there is no existing collection of resolvedItems to manipulate: it would therefore be impossible to manipulate the results of the OOTB resolvers.

1. How can I execute my custom resolver (addon) AFTER all other resolvers?
2. How can I control (configure) the execution order of multiple custom resolver addons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems indeed that custom resolver addons are executed BEFORE any OOTB resolvers (standard and DXA)

1. There is currently no way to control that custom resolver addons are executed AFTER all other (OOTB) resolvers.
2. There is currently no way to control the execution order of multiple custom resolver addons.

We have requested fixes/enhancements with CS.

Comment: Both issues confirmed by R&D.
A hotfix is created for the first issue, the second issue will be dealt with in future product updates.